# C array of pointers changing address randomly

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing code for a Postfix Calculator, for which I need to add tokens and values("a=5", "b=10") to an Array of Pointers.

This array of pointers is used as I'm implementing Separate Chaining. Therefore, each index is the beginning of a linked list of tokens and values.
However, there is this weird error/bug, such that the addresses of the pointers in the array (which begin as all NULL's), change in between when no memory access or address change is made at that Pointer.
This happens in between parsing through the Array of Pointers.
The image here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2AVu.png) shows exactly what happened when I ran GDB on the program. The red arrow indicated the line being executed. The blue region is the memory being watched and the highlighted line in yellow shows that the address has changed. You can see that the previous addresses for the same symtab->table[3] are all equal to NULL ({0x0}).
Any idea why this is happening?
The code itself is here below,

```
//This part of the program iterates through each linked list
//Previous declaration of Array of Pointers- 
//Symbol* localArrayOfPointers[HASH_TABLE_INITIAL]
Symbol** current = symtab->table;
  for (int i = 0; i < hash_get_capacity(symtab); i++)
  { //The address changes in between here I believe
    if(current[i] == NULL){
      continue;
    }
    else{
//Other code omitted as there is nothing changing any addresses
```

Answer (score 2):

An uninitialized pointer doesn't have to be a NULL pointer, it can point to any address, so the expression in "if" is always false unless it has been assigned to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with current declaration.

Array of pointers means `Symbol *current[n]`.
In your code, it's a pointer to a pointer (a double pointer). But, I understand that you need an array of pointers.

You are indexing a double pointer and checking for equality with null. So, that needs to be an array of pointers.

Comment: The declaration of the array pointer is actually in another part of the program. It was done as - Symbol* linkedList[HASH_TABLE_INITIAL]; . This part of the program just iterates through each linked list.